Fake Backend, real backend vs aer simulator results
I initialised a circuit that creates a random state and then performed some calculations.
I dont change the state and perform repeated calculations using that state. I get a singular value around 0.25 varying by little when I use aer-simulator as backend. But when I use the real ibm_brisbane or fakebrisbane, the values fluctuate a lot. Why does this happen because the way I understand is that if I have the circuit initialised and I am taking that input and performing calculations again and again, I should not get fluctuations as is the case with aer-simulator? Why does the real thing and it's fake backend give such odd results?
Also on a side note how does the aer-simulator work I checked the documentation but could not understand. I understand that these might be naive questions but I am really lost as I am very new to quantum computation. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Real backends are noisy. Fake backends incorporate noise models to "emulate" the noisy behavior of real backends. The Aer backend is an ideal simulator, unless you specify a noise model. The Aer simulator basically uses a pseudo-random number generator to sample a distribution of possible states using the probabilities dictated by the amplitudes of the quantum state.
